# Rails: Cannot use Stripe token more than once - [Stripe::InvalidRequestError]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe checkout in a Rails 4x app. My goal is to provide monthly subscriptions. I'm receiving the following.

Stripe::InvalidRequestError Cannot use stripeToken more than once. This happens when `create_stripe_subscription` is called in `subscriptions_controller#create`.

In spite of this error message, I have customers who have made charges that appear in my stripe dashboard.

I'd like to learn where I'm duplicating this one-time-usage token and understand what stripe is requiring for this subscription.

Here are associated files & images to demonstrate what my implementation efforts are looking like so far.

initializers/stripe.rb:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: ENV["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"],
  secret_key: ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

subscriptions/new (the "small" plan's stripe checkout button)

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" 
class="stripe-button",
  data-key="<%= ENV["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>",
  data-email="<%= current_employee.email %>",
  data-image="app/assets/images/mascot_favicon.ico",
  data-name="Small Group Home",
  data-description="Monthly subcription plan",
  data-amount="<%= @small_plan.amount %>",
  data-id="<%= @small_plan.id %>",
  data-label="Subscribe!">
</script>
```

subscriptions_controller.rb

```
def create
  create_stripe_subscription

  if create_stripe_subscription.valid?
    AdminMailer.welcome_email(@admin).deliver_now
    flash[:success] = "#{ @admin.full_name.pluralize } created!"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:notice] = "There was a problem with the form"
    render :new
  end
end
.    
.
.
def create_stripe_subscription 
  plan_id = params[:plan_id]
  plan = Stripe::Plan.retrieve(plan_id)
  token = params[:stripeToken]
  email = params[:stripeEmail] 

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    source: token,
    email: email,
    plan: plan
  )

  subscription = Subscription.new
  subscription.stripe_card_token = customer.id

  same_customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(subscription.stripe_card_token)
  same_customer.subscriptions.create(plan: params[:plan_id])
end
```

**stipe dash**

[image: customer record on stripe]
[image: subscription success]

Comment: Hiya, it's very hard for us to debug a verbal description of your code... Please edit your question and add the *relevant* sections of your code that deals with stripe.

Comment: Hey thanks for such a prompt reply! I've made the edits to more clearly state where my issue is. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: It looks like you're including your secret API key in your client-side code as a meta tag. That is unnecessary and a huge security flaw -- with your secret  API key, anyone can do basically anything with your account (create charges, refunds, delete data, etc.)

Comment: If you have a bunch of code that is are directly related than use different code blocks to format it. You can use `---` to separate code blocks or just don't indent the description of the file. Its really hard to scroll though a code block with many lines.

Comment: Also your `initializers/stripe.rb` is just plain silly. You don't need the `if Rails.env ==  "production"` - just use different env vars in development and production - thats the whole point of using them.

Comment: Thanks @Ywain, I added that in last minute to see if it would help, I understand what you're saying however and have removed the meta tag. Appreciate the point out.

Comment: @max I appreciate the editing help, my goal is to make this question easily readable for others.

Comment: As an update, I haven't yet been able to get past this InvalidRequestError. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by handling the `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` in the `create_stripe_subscription method` like so:

subscriptions_controller.rb

```
def create_stripe_subscription
.
.
.
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  logger.error "Stripe error: #{e.message}"
end
```

Which led me to a noMethodError from my app. Then error came from this line in my subscriptions_controller's create method.

```
if create_stripe_subscription.valid?
```

Removing `valid?` allowed the create method to finish up, sending the email and redirecting as it should.

Comment: Just noticed that I still see this Stripe error in my server logs.

Comment: I was calling the method create_stripe_subscription twice. Once at the beginning of my subscriptions_controller#create method and right below it in a conditional. Deleting the first call removed the error completely from my logs.